# When is FlixTrain coming to Sweden?

Tags: event-based-effects, sweden, flixbus, flixtrain

As one who is travelling between Gothenburg and Stockholm all the time I can't wait for the FlixTrains to arrive. The service was supposed to be [launched early this year](https://www.railjournal.com/passenger/main-line/flixtrain-to-launch-stockholm-gothenburg-malmo-services-next-year/) but I haven't heard anything about it for a long time.

When is FlixTrain being launched in Sweden?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FlixTrain [was launched](https://corporate.flixbus.com/flixtrain-expands-in-europe-green-long-distance-trains-start-in-sweden/) in Sweden on May the 6th 2021.

The Stockholm-based company [Hector Rail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hector_Rail) is in charge of the operations.

Answer (score 2):

I'm probably coming a bit late but there are Flixtrain-branded trainsets parked near Gothenburg Central, so it seems the project is still moving forward and hopefully going to launch soon (although personally I'm not a fan of Flixanything but more competition is always a good thing :)).

Answer (score 1):

A poster [here](https://www.postvagnen.com/sjk-forum/showthread.php/11762-FlixTrain?p=90563&viewfull=1#post90563) says that at least some of their assigned schedule is cancelled until Aug 30, which is short after the track closure between Malmö and Lund. So it would surprise me if they start before August (between Stockholm and Gothenburg they could start in mid August after the track closure in Stockholm), rather they might continue to push the launch forward until they are ready.

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t find any more info but see [this news article from September 2019:](https://www.railjournal.com/passenger/main-line/flixtrain-to-launch-stockholm-gothenburg-malmo-services-next-year/)

> FLIXTRAIN confirmed on September 23 that it is planning to enter the Swedish market with the aim of launching new services from Stockholm to Gothenburg and Malmö in 2020.

Comment: Flix mobility taking over ticket sales and marketting for MTR Express?

Comment: @KristvanBesien is MTR Express shutting down?

Comment: Don’t know.  But I do know that Flixbus/Flixtrain actually does not run any buses or trains. Flixmobility does the network development, marketting and ticket sales. The actual operation is always done via subcontractors. For example, in Germany Flixtrain is actually Leo Express. So I wonder who’s trains it is going to be.

Comment: @KristvanBesien MTR Express seems like a reasonable option.